# Extratropical transition of tropical cyclone

Tags: tropical-cyclone, cyclone

I am a beginner of learning Tropical Cyclone. I would like to represent the extratropical transition of a tropical cyclone. But I can't understand on what actually in need to focus.

For a tropical cyclone, I can calculate time series of rainfall, maximum wind speed, minimum sea level pressure and discuss its features. Similarly, what are the quantities I should calculate to represent the extratropical transitions of the same tropical cyclone? and What actually I need to show?

Is it just simple discuss how a tropical cyclone changes its behavior when it moves toward the higher latitudes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not sufficient to just discuss the behavior as it moves into higher latitudes. ET occurs because of environmental reasons, not geographical reasons.

How much of a beginner are you? My answer below may be a bit over your head if you do not know much about tropical cyclones. If that is the case, I suggest looking back at the theory and [basics](https://www.meted.ucar.edu/training_module.php?id=868#.XnubT4hKhPY) of tropical cyclones (structure, maximum potential intensity, etc.) to get a good grasp of what separates tropical cyclones from extratropical cyclones.

If you are specifically looking at quantities, I suggest looking at [cyclone phase space diagrams](https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/full/10.1175/1520-0493%282003%29131%3C0585%3AACPSDF%3E2.0.CO%3B2). The variables in these diagrams include the thermal wind for different levels, as well as baroclinicity. [FSU has examples of cyclone phase space diagrams for different storms.](http://moe.met.fsu.edu/cyclonephase/)

Edit: I remembered two recent articles that review ET. They are [Evans et al. (2017)](https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/full/10.1175/MWR-D-17-0027.1) and [Keller et al. (2019)](https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/full/10.1175/MWR-D-17-0329.1).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and materials. I am very beginner. Now I am going through these materials and may come back if I need more help.